# Gradle Test Executor finished with non-zero exit code

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Using Gradle 2.12 with

```
org.gradle.daemon=false
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
org.gradle.parallel=false
```

in gradle.properties

```
:app:processDevDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDevDebugUnitTestJavaRes
:app:compileDevDebugUnitTestSources
:app:mockableAndroidJar
:app:assembleDevDebugUnitTest
:app:testDevDebugUnitTest
objc[16261]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
:app:testDevDebugUnitTest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:testDevDebugUnitTest'.
> Process 'Gradle Test Executor 1' finished with non-zero exit value 10
```

When run with stacktrace

```
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'Gradle Test Executor 1' finished with non-zero exit value 10
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:367)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultWorkerProcess.waitForStop(DefaultWorkerProcess.java:161)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.ForkingTestClassProcessor.stop(ForkingTestClassProcessor.java:89)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.processors.RestartEveryNTestClassProcessor.endBatch(RestartEveryNTestClassProcessor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.processors.RestartEveryNTestClassProcessor.stop(RestartEveryNTestClassProcessor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.FailureHandlingDispatch.dispatch(FailureHandlingDispatch.java:29)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.dispatchMessages(AsyncDispatch.java:132)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.access$000(AsyncDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.AsyncDispatch$1.run(AsyncDispatch.java:72)
```

When run with --debug : (Ive redacted some test names)

```
14:41:18.772 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] <REDACTED>ActionBarTest STARTED
14:41:18.907 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]
14:41:18.907 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] <REDACTED>ActionBarTest > shouldRegisterTimeChangeBroadcastReceiverOnStart STARTED
14:41:23.158 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]
14:41:23.158 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] <REDACTED>ActionBarTest > shouldRegisterTimeChangeBroadcastReceiverOnStart PASSED
14:41:23.159 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]
14:41:23.159 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] <REDACTED>ActionBarTest > shouldShoBlahdAsTitle STARTED
14:41:23.666 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection] Discarding EOFException: java.io.EOFException
14:41:23.667 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: FAILED
14:41:23.667 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Process 'Gradle Test Executor 1' finished with exit value 10 (state: FAILED)
14:41:23.669 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]
14:41:23.669 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] Gradle Test Run :app:testDevDebugUnitTest PASSED
14:41:23.669 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':app:testDevDebugUnitTest'
14:41:23.669 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :app:testDevDebugUnitTest FAILED
14:41:23.670 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :app:testDevDebugUnitTest (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 4,5,main]) completed. Took 5.807 secs.
14:41:23.670 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Daemon worker Thread 4,5,main]] finished, busy: 6.945 secs, idle: 0.007 secs
14:41:23.670 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
14:41:23.672 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
14:41:23.672 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
14:41:23.672 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
14:41:23.672 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:testDevDebugUnitTest'.
14:41:23.672 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > Process 'Gradle Test Executor 1' finished with non-zero exit value 10
```

What causes the exec exception? `./gradlew test` fails frequently with this error.

Comment: Did you figure out what the problem was?

Comment: Yes. I added my resolution notes below in the answer

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you face this issue: look for

1. The exit code. This exit code will be in our sources, or
2. Other 3rd party libs / error handling frameworks that were somehow invoked when running the test suite.

We were using a library to log errors: [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) and this library, was invoked when running the test suite, and caused an exit of the entire VM. The library internally has a

```
System.exit(1)
```

which **killed** the gradle/jvm process that runs test suite.

The JVM exit was in turn caused by another error, an NPE, which was caught by ACRA (an error handling library), that tried to record the NPE and ended up reaching the `System.exit()` code which stopped the test executor VM.